# How to kill process by clicking back button in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, back, kill-process

I have made an application in android .It is an application related to timer.Now i have tried a lot to put controll on back button of android device that when it is pressed the process should be killed and directly displays main menu...Please help me...Thanking you in advance..![image]

Comment: what do you mean by main menu ? Main menu of your Application or main menu of the Device ?

Comment: which process? What do you mean by main menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   yourActivity.this.finish;
}
```

Comment: @Priya-but can u please tell me..if i want this happened with all the activities in my application.should i add this code to all the activity?

Comment: @jimmycool you can add to all acitivties, it ll finish the activity on press of back button.

Comment: @Priya-NO NO u didn't get me..i've use ur code in each activity but its working like when i Presseing back button its going to Previous Activity ,rather go to main screen of device...!do you get my problem now???

Comment: you can use this code to go to main screen onBackPressed.                                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Priya-u didn't get me still....m talking bout the main screen of device,not of application..and its not working...:(

Comment: @jimmycool- you can use this code to go to main screen of ur device----  finish();
moveTaskToBack(true);
System.exit(0);

Answer (score 2):

override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and add your necessary codes there

[onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this **onclick of back button.**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         finish();// call finish() on click of back button
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**for example :** When you **moving from A activity to B activity** using startActivity(new intent(...)); **don't finish or kill A activity, It ll be in stack**.`So when you click on back button in B activity you can go back to A activity, which is already in stack.`

**when you want to go back to main menu call finish() on every activity when your moving to next activity**.

**for example :** When you **moving from A activity to B activity** using startActivity(new intent(...)); call `finish()` to kill A activity.`So when you click on back button in B activity you can go back to Main Menu coz every activity ll be killed.`

snippet is here :

```
startActivity(new intent(A.this, B.class));
finish(); // when you click back button on B activity, directly you can go to main menu
```

**Updated :** 
Other way to kill the app using below code on back button pressed. **But not recommended**

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());// Kill the app on click of back button.
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

hope this might help you to understand the concept.

Comment: Sir..thanking you....for this..but i want is that from any activity in the project when i press back button it should kill the process and directly go to main menu...can u please help me for this? thank you sir..!

Comment: simple.. when your moving to next activity call finish(), so it ll remove from the stack

Comment: NO NO you not getting what m saying...I want that from any stage of running application if m pressing the back button,the process should be killed and the controll should directly go to main menu rather the Previous page..!

Comment: exactly, you call finish() on every activity. so when you press back button you ll goto main menu

Comment: @TechEnd-u not getting ..bro.."mainmenu" means the mainscreen of device...now u get my problem?please help me..

Comment: I got your problem... accroding to that itself I have updated my answer.. have you tried above solutions which I have given.. how many activity you have ??

Comment: @TechEnd-we'll i've 4 activities..in my app.

Comment: @jimmycool how your going from one activity to another activity ?

Comment: @TechEnd-By using "intent"..!

Comment: @Techend-public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       
      
        Intent intent= new Intent(ListActivity.this,NewProject.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
      }
     });

Comment: are you performing or calling this finish(); in all activity ??

Comment: then call onKeyDown(...) at last in every activity it ll work

Comment: @TechEnd-Good morning sir...sir i'd tried it..but its not going to the main screen of emulator,its just going to previous page..!when i pressing back button...Sir i have added screenshots...so u can better get my problem..thank you

Comment: @jimmycool -- very gud mrng... do one thing.. add the last snippet which I have given in answer add to all file..

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the activity history so that your application gets closed.And call `finsh();` after`startActivity();`

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.abcd.Your_Acitivty"
        android:noHistory="true">
  </activity>
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: i think this one is not working. It keeps using memory even when i use noHistory and call finish().

Answer (score 0):

well jimmy you can use this code to go to main screen of your device-

```
    finish();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
     System.exit(0);
```

**finish()** method closes current Activity only.

**moveTasktoBack** will hide your app and You can also kill an application quickly via **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())** if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't even finish current activity - it only hides it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest, you could try adding this

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
</activity>
```

I was having a similar issue, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by override onBackPress() and onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    System.exit(0); //kill the app

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() { //here I capture the event onBackPress 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    onStop(); //call onStop
}
```