# Kill the application when the home button is triggered

Tags: android

I want to kill the application when the user presses the home button. I can detect the home key but when the kill the application using the below code

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Only the particular activity is killed not the whole application. So when i relaunch the application it was coming from the Previous Activity

**Example Flow:**

FirstActivity --> SecondActivity --> Third Activity --> Home Pressed on ThirdActivity --> Relaunch the app coming from the SecondActivity (Should come from FirstActivity)

Please Help me
Thanks

Comment: First kill second activity before you kill the app...!!

Comment: Sorry please check the edited question

Comment: You can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY in your first activity

Comment: You cannot override the home button after ICS i.e 4.0+

Answer (score 0):

Sorry This is not possible. As documentation of android says. `You nedd to follow Activity Lifecycle.`

Here Activity will be `stack one upon another`. So when you got thru third activity you nedd to finish two activity.

otherwise you activity will start from last stack of activity

For better understanding see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: then how does the killProcess comes into picture?

Comment: Kill is for the Activity not for all Application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109794/how-to-kill-process-by-clicking-back-button-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then how to kill the complete application when i was in the middle of the stack

Comment: moving to second Activity call finish() before startActivity in first activity. override onBackPressed in second activity and call First Activity on back press. Now when home is press kill current activity as you doing. Following this steps will not have any activity in stack. so opening again application start from the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

U need to clear top. Try this-
1. Launch any activity when you want to exit-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, end.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

2.in end activity call finish in onCreate()

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

The way you should implement this depends a bit on what kind of flow you want your application to have.

Do you ever want to be able to resume from `SecondActivity` or `ThirdActivity`? If not, there's a handy parameter you can add to your `<activity>` in the manifest:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

This flag means that when the user leaves that `Activity`, it will not be kept on the activity stack. This is effectively the same as calling `finish()` on the `Activity` when the user leaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
 add activity in to stack when move from one activity to another... 

by calling 
             Activities app = new Activities();
            app.addBackActivity((Activity) MYClass.this);



and remove all activty by calling 

               act.finishAll();



   public class Activities{

        public static Stack<Activity> classes = new Stack<Activity>();

          public Activity getBackActivity() {
            return classes.pop();
          }

          public void addBackActivity(Activity activity) {
            classes.push(activity);
          }

          public void finishAll(){

              for(int i=0;i<classes.size();i++){
                  classes.get(i).finish();
              }
              classes.clear();

          }

        }
```